# Can I change the rootViewController to a different storyboard view inside ViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, uistoryboard, viewcontroller

I have some logic that requires a different `view` to appear once a `button` is pressed. This code bellow works from the `appDelegate` but not in my `ViewController` implementation. Is there a way to change the view controller storyboard from the current `ViewController` implementation?

```
self.window.rootViewController =
(UIViewController *)[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"homeView"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Along as the controller's view is currently on screen, it has a non-nil window property that points to its window. Also, if the controller with this code was made in the same storyboard, you can just use self.storyboard instead of getting a storyboard from its name.

```
    self.view.window.rootViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"homeView"];
```

Comment: Both answers are valid but this one is the more concise.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `window` from the `UIApplication` instance:

```
UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
UIViewController *newRoot = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"homeView"];
[(AppDelegate *)application.delegate window].rootViewController = newRoot;
```